# Getting word count of a file in Ruby and not open to Command Injection

Tags: ruby

How do I get the line count of a file into a variable in Ruby using the Unix command wc for speed for very large files whilst making sure that it's safe from command injection using either open3, system or something similar to achieve the same output as `` `wc -l < "#{file_path}".to_i` ``

Comment: you mean that the file path will be provided by users? or that there can be commands in the file you don't want to be executed?

Comment: I was only thinking about about commands in the filename from the file path provided by users

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest is to use [`Open3::capture2`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2):

```
output, status = Open3::capture2('wc', '-l', file_path)
```

Then you can check `status` and deal with errors as needed and since `output` should be something like `"    2342 file_path\n"`, you can get the count with a simple `#to_i` call:

```
line_count = output.to_i
```

If you don't care about error handling (which would never happen in real life):

```
line_count = Open3::capture2('wc', '-l', file_path).first.to_i
```

No shell will be involved, no command injection issues.

However, this assumes that the first `wc` in your `PATH` is the `wc` you want to use so you might want to be more specific:

```
# Or ensure that your PATH environment variable is sensible.
output, status = Open3::capture2('/usr/bin/wc', '-l', file_path)
```

This also assumes that you want the users to be able to read any file that your process can; if that's not the case then you'd need to blacklist/whitelist `file_path` to make sure it is something that they're supposed to be able to read.

Of course, if you're going to all this trouble you might as well open the file and count the lines yourself with a couple lines of Ruby:

```
# Or some variation on this and a `rescue` to catch exceptions.
line_count = File.open('Gemfile') { |fp| fp.each_line.count }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use native shell command and the only thing you want is to *escape* **file_path**, there is a [Shellwords](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) class in the standard library.

It's very easy to use it in your task:

```
require 'shellwords'

`wc -l < #{Shellwords.escape(file_path)}`.to_i
```